# Merge Brush and BitmapImage Together

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to take a brush that is applied to a button's background and render a BitmapImage ontop of it, thus merging the images and setting it to the background.

```
RenderTargetBitmap source = new RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(button.RenderSize.Width), Convert.ToInt32(button.RenderSize.Height), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(button.Background, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(button.RenderSize.Width, button.RenderSize.Height)));
    drawingContext.Close();
    source.Render(visual);
}

visual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    context.DrawImage(source, new Rect());
    context.DrawImage(image, new Rect());
    context.Close();
}

source.Render(visual);
```

However, I cannot set the RenderTargetBitmap to the Background property of the button. I'm not even sure if this is the best way of doing such a thing.

If I can convert the RenderTargetBitmap to a brush, is this the most effective approach?

Cheers.

Comment: Can't you just add the bitmap to the button's content, rather than trying to make it part of the background? If not, why not? It would be better if you could include a good, concise, complete code example demonstrating what you're actually trying to do here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The button's content is already set by another piece of content. The button is a customized UserControl and the Background property is the only thing left for me to manipulate to do this without changing a lot of code.

Comment: Can you wrap the existing content? I.e. retrieve the current `Content` element and replace it with e.g. a `Canvas` or `Grid` object that contains your bitmap, and then the original element on top of it? If you really are able to change only the `Background` property, then of course you will need to create a `Brush` to assign to it. That's its type! :)

Answer (score 0):

We have many ways to do this using codebehind, but I would try to use XAML code here. The idea is using some `DrawingBrush` for the background. This brush requires some `Drawing`. We can use a `DrawingGroup` here, because it allows us to append multiple Drawings. We just care about the `GeometryDrawing` and `ImageDrawing` here. The `GeometryDrawing` can render a brush using simple `RectangleGeometry` while the `ImageDrawing` can render an image. Here is the sample XAML code, I suppose you put the inputs including input `brush` and input `image` as some resources:

```
<DrawingBrush>
   <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
      <DrawingGroup>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource someBrush}">
           <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1"/>
           </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
        <ImageDrawing ImageSource="{StaticResource someImage}" Rect="0,0,1,1"/>
      </DrawingGroup>
   </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Note that when using the above brush for some Background, normally it would fill the whole element. So the `Rect` is not important here, we can set it (for both RectangleGeometry and ImageDrawing) to the same value. However when you set some tiled background, that Rect may be important to care about. You should then set it to some other value.

In the code above, the `ImageDrawing` is declared after the `GeometryDrawing` so it will be rendered on top of the `GeometryDrawing`. That means the later declared drawings will be on top of the before ones. Here is the result in which I declared the `GeometryDrawing` (rendering a `LinearGradientBrush` from green to red) after the `ImageDrawing` so that you can see the transparent effect of the LinearGradientBrush:

[image]